# TicTacToe Draw Condition in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have nine labels ranged from label1-label9 and arranged as 3x3 grid. So it should look like

label1 label2 label3

label4 label5 label6

label7 label8 label9

The win condition of tic tac toe is when the conditions r met like picture below :

[Win Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4k8L.jpg)

So based on that conditions I can write :

```
 Public Sub winCondition()

    If Label1.Text = "x" And Label2.Text = "x" And Label3.Text = "x" Then
        Call xWin()
    ElseIf Label4.Text = "x" And Label5.Text = "x" And Label6.Text = "x" Then
        Call xWin()
    ElseIf Label7.Text = "x" And Label8.Text = "x" And Label9.Text = "x" Then
        Call xWin()
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "x" And Label4.Text = "x" And Label7.Text = "x" Then
        Call xWin()
    ElseIf Label2.Text = "x" And Label5.Text = "x" And Label8.Text = "x" Then
        Call xWin()
    ElseIf Label3.Text = "x" And Label6.Text = "x" And Label9.Text = "x" Then
        Call xWin()
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "x" And Label5.Text = "x" And Label9.Text = "x" Then
        Call xWin()
    ElseIf Label3.Text = "x" And Label5.Text = "x" And Label7.Text = "x" Then
        Call xWin()
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "o" And Label2.Text = "o" And Label3.Text = "o" Then
        Call oWin()
    ElseIf Label4.Text = "o" And Label5.Text = "o" And Label6.Text = "o" Then
        Call oWin()
    ElseIf Label7.Text = "o" And Label8.Text = "o" And Label9.Text = "o" Then
        Call oWin()
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "o" And Label4.Text = "o" And Label7.Text = "o" Then
        Call oWin()
    ElseIf Label2.Text = "o" And Label5.Text = "o" And Label8.Text = "o" Then
        Call oWin()
    ElseIf Label3.Text = "o" And Label6.Text = "o" And Label9.Text = "o" Then
        Call oWin()
    ElseIf Label1.Text = "o" And Label5.Text = "o" And Label9.Text = "o" Then
        Call oWin()
    ElseIf Label3.Text = "o" And Label5.Text = "o" And Label7.Text = "o" Then
        Call oWin()

    End If

    If Form1.Label3.Text <> "0" And Form1.Label4.Text <> "0" Then
        imbang()
    End If
End Sub
```

The xWin and oWin procedures r just displaying messageBox.
I also have another codes in modules. But the basic logic is like that.

Now for the draw condition, basically if all blocks are filled with x and o but doesn't meet the winning condition like above then it'll be draw (it'll show messagebpox that say that it's draw).

How do I do that?

Comment: if the glob of code is complete on testing for wins, wouldnt a draw just be `oWin = False AndAlso xWin = False`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter set to zero at the start of each game. Each time somebody makes a move, add one to the counter. At then end of the wincondition checking, add a final elsif to see if the counter has reached nine and call a draw if it has.